# Probability that multiple exponential events happen

Tags: probability

If you want to know what is the probability that exactly k events that are all exponentially distributed with parameter \mu happen in a fixed time interval then this is a Poisson process with rate \mu. But what if you want to know the probability that k exponential evetns, that are all exponentials with different rates, happen in a fixed time interval ? So in the case that the exponential rv's are not homogeneous but heterogeneous.

Comment: Should "k events happen" be "k events happen in a fixed time interval"?

Comment: yes  that is true